# Druid doesn't support number?

Tags: druid

I'm working with Druid `0.8.2` and i tried to import number (as a dimension) with Tranquility.

I'd this error :
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dimensions of type[FLOAT] are not supported`

I read that Druid `0.8.2` doesn't support number. Is it true ? If it is, I must use type `string` in my dimensions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dimension columns in Druid must be strings. If you have a float field - it is most likely a Metric. I use this rule of thumb - if I can think of a query that uses a column in a `GROUP BY` statement - it's a dimension, otherwise, it's most likely a metric(a value being measured, whether the dimension is an attribute of a measurement).

Explanation of a difference between dimensions and metrics - https://altitudemarketing.com/blog/metrics-vs-dimensions-difference/

If you are sure that your Float column is a dimension, then you need to convert it to string type, otherwise, don't mark it as a dimension and leave it as float type(which is supported for metrics)